Does Sheafification Commute with Quotients
This is probably just a diagram argument, but I can't figure out the right ones. Given two presheafs $\mathscr{F}$ and $\mathscr{G}$, is $(\mathscr{F} / \mathscr{G})^+ \cong (\mathscr{F}^+ / \mathscr{G}^+)^+$? Here the $(\cdot)^ +$ indicates the sheafification.
In particular, I'm working on an exercise from Hartshorne, and it'd be nice if given a constant presheaf $\mathscr{A}$ with sheafification $\mathscr{H}$ and a sheaf $\mathscr{O}$, $(\mathscr{A} / \mathscr{O})^+ \cong (\mathscr{H} / \mathscr{O})^+$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sheafification is a left adjoint, quotients are colimits, and in general left adjoints preserve colimits

I think it mainly boils down to two facts:

Sheafification is exact (because sheafification preserves stalks).
Quotients are unique (at least in the Abelian categories of sheaves in Hartshorne).

As a start take the short exact sequence of presheaves
\begin{equation}
0 \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G} \to 0.
\end{equation}
Then immediately from exactness of sheafification we get the short exact sequence
\begin{equation}
0 \to \mathcal{F}^+ \to \mathcal{G}^+ \to (\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G})^+ \to 0.
\end{equation}
But because the quotient of objects is unique this expresses $(\mathcal{F}^+/\mathcal{G}^+)^+$ exactly as $(\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{G})^+$
